# Android Accessibility Voice assistant issue in Recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview, samsung-mobile, talkback, accessibility

I have turned on my voice assistant in on in my Note 5 and trying to move forward (up to down) but it is going out of Recyclerview when it reaches to end of the screen.
As there are many more items in the list so it should auto-scroll up.

I have observed this issue in **Samsung Note 5 and Samsung Note 9** but it is working fine in **Samsung 9 and Samsung 9+**.

I have maintained focusable true in every item of RecyclerView.
I have used a solution but i don't think it is the best one can anyone suggest me what would be the best approach.

My solution: I am manually scrolling the list by detecting the moment.

#### RecyclerView

`<RecyclerView>.setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(RVAccessibilityDelegate(<RecyclerView>, <No of item you want to scroll>))`

#### RVAccessibilityDelegate

````
   RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate(recyclerView){

   private var previousItemPosition = 0

   override fun onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host: ViewGroup, child: View, event: AccessibilityEvent): Boolean {

       if (event.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {


           if (host is RecyclerView) {

               var childPosition = host.getChildAdapterPosition(child)

               if (childPosition == 0 && previousItemPosition == 0) {

                   host.smoothScrollToPosition(1)

               } else if (previousItemPosition < childPosition) {

                   host.smoothScrollToPosition(childPosition + scrollItem)
                   previousItemPosition = childPosition

               } else if (previousItemPosition > childPosition) {

                   var scrollUpto = childPosition - scrollItem
                   if (scrollUpto < 0) {
                       scrollUpto = 0
                   }
                   if (childPosition == 0) {
                       host.smoothScrollToPosition(childPosition)
                   } else {
                       host.smoothScrollToPosition(scrollUpto)
                   }
                   previousItemPosition = childPosition
               }
           }

           return true
       }
       return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host, child, event)
   }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of the code:

```
recyclerView.setAccessibilityDelegateCompat(object : RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate(recyclerView) {

    private var previousItemPosition = 0

    override fun onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host: ViewGroup, child: View, event: AccessibilityEvent): Boolean {
        if (event.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
            if (host is RecyclerView) {
                val childPosition = host.getChildAdapterPosition(child)
                if (previousItemPosition < childPosition) {
                    host.smoothScrollToPosition(childPosition + 1)
                } else if (previousItemPosition > childPosition) {
                    host.smoothScrollToPosition(Math.max(0, childPosition - 1))
                }
                previousItemPosition = childPosition
            }
            return true
        }
        return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host, child, event)
    }
})
```

Comment: This is not an answer, is it?

Comment: Oh cool. Would you mind explaining a bit more? Can't tell by reading the code